# Вычисление интеграла с применением мемоизации на Clojure

Tags: clojure

Есть задача:

Реализовать функцию (оператор), принимающую аргументом функцию от одной переменной f и возвращающую функцию одной переменной, вычисляющую (численно) выражение:

[image: Определенный интеграл]

Оптимизировать с использованием мемоизации для задач типа построения графиков (т.е. многократный вызов функции в разных точках)
Использовать метод трапеций с постоянным шагом.

```
    (defn trapeze [f x1 x2]
  (*
    (/
      (+ (f x1) (f x2))
      2)
    (Math/abs (- x2 x1))))

(defn integrate [f delta]
  (let [f_memo f
        generate (fn [sum [x1 integral]]
                    (let [x2 (sum x1 delta)]
                      [x2 (+ integral (trapeze f_memo x1 x2))]))
        seq_pos (map first (iterate (partial generate +) [0 0]))
        seq_neg (map first (iterate (partial generate -) [0 0]))]
    (fn [x]
      (let [seq (if (pos? x) seq_pos seq_neg)
            sign (if (neg? x) -1 1)
            x (Math/abs x)
            steps (quot x delta)
            tail (mod x delta)]
        (+
          (nth seq steps)
          (trapeze f_memo
            (* sign (- x tail))
            (* sign x)))
        ))))
```

Есть проблема с выделенной частью задачи - не могу разобраться с мемоизацией. Кто знает как правильно вынести вычисление частичных сумм и мемоизировать это?

Comment: Какую функцию вы конкретно пытаетесь запомнить? (Я не русский. Извините, если перевод плох).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm trying to memorize the function of a partial amount, but I don’t know yet how to get it out of the main function